display_columncounts will not work if col_counts is specified
remove N=xx frmo header is not working if col_counts is given:
library(rtables)

lyt3 <- basic_table(show_colcounts = FALSE) %>%
  split_cols_by("ARM") %>%
  analyze("AGE", afun = function(x) {
    setNames(as.list(fivenum(x)), c(
      "minimum", "lower-hinge", "median",
      "upper-hinge", "maximum"
    ))
  })

tbl6 <- build_table(lyt3, DM, col_counts = 1:3)
tbl6@col_info@display_columncounts <- FALSE  
tbl6

then you will have this:
> tbl6
              A: Drug X   B: Placebo   C: Combination
                (N=1)       (N=2)          (N=3)     
—————————————————————————————————————————————————————
minimum          20           21             22      
lower-hinge      29           29             30      
median           33           32             33      
upper-hinge      39           37             38      
maximum          60           55             53      

yet, this is what I expected:
> tbl6
              A: Drug X   B: Placebo   C: Combination
—————————————————————————————————————————————————————
minimum          20           21             22      
lower-hinge      29           29             30      
median           33           32             33      
upper-hinge      39           37             38      
maximum          60           55             53    

Thanks for checking!!

based on above Garini's indication, please try below code, colcounts could be invisible:
leaf_paths <- col_paths(tbl6)
for (pth in leaf_paths) {
  colcount_visible(tbl6, pth) <- FALSE
}

tbl6


If you add col_counts in build_table(), then the values are added to the object and the display option is overridden. It is enough to do col_counts = NULL when building the table. A trick that you can implement if you want mixed behavior is to do col_counts(tbl6) <- c(NA, 2, 3).
Note: Remember never to access internal variables with @. If one is or should be accessible, we provide a getter and (sometimes) a setter for those.

Thank you very much, Garini, it did work! Yet, it left a extra empty row, do you know how can I remoe that blank row?

No I do not know, but I think your best bet is to have an if() else for setting col_counts to NULL if you do not want the column counts
